# Paging in Angular JS

Tags: css, angularjs, pagination

I am using Angular 1 and using dir-paginate control for paging. But needs to show as 10|25|50|100|All option in bottom and top of the page. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

```
<tr dir-paginate="r in model | orderBy: key : AscOrDesc |  filter : model | itemsPerPage: 25 ">

 <dir-pagination-controls max-size="25" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" auto-hide="false"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a scope variable for itemsPerPage in controller and set default number of items

eg.,

```
$scope.pageSize = 10; // default items per page
```

and assign this scope variable into itemsPerPage filter as like below

```
`<tr dir-paginate="r in model | orderBy: key : AscOrDesc |  filter : model | itemsPerPage: pageSize ">`

 `<dir-pagination-controls max-size="25" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" auto-hide="false"></dir-pagination-controls>`
```

and you can have list of option links through which itemsPerPage value can be get updated

```
`<div class="option-list">
   <a href="#" ng-click="pageSize=5">5</a>
   <a href="#" ng-click="pageSize=10">10</a>
   <a href="#" ng-click="pageSize=25">25</a>
   <a href="#" ng-click="pageSize=All">All</a>
</div>`
```

Find working code here - http://plnkr.co/edit/peFiAzDKRKX5IKgHum5y?p=preview